# Need to implement #cache! if you want to use Cloudinary::CarrierWave::Storage as cache storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, cloudinary

Need to implement #cache! if you want to use Cloudinary::CarrierWave::Storage as cache storage. I am facing this issue to uploading an image for our blog in ruby on rails. Please tell me how I am Fix this Issue. [**Backbenchersstudy**](https://www.backbenchersstudy.com)

Answer (score 0):

Cloudinary is currently not indented to be used as cache storage. However, as part of CarrierWave 2.0 updates [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/commit/629afecbaeccd2300e4660b78ee36bd95dd845c5), the behaviour was changed so that the default cache storage is now configured to be the same as the regular upload hence the error.

You can use the below configuration to set the cache storage to file instead of it trying to use Cloudinary.

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.cache_storage = :file
end
```

Related thread:
https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/issues/344